# How do I return a character given the function has integer return data type?

Tags: c

I was given a skeleton code to build an AddressBook program in C language. The code gives me a helper function get_option() to obtain user input that returns an integer. The driver code, however, requires me to return a character from using get_option(). Please help
[get_option() function and the function that calls get_option()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B56ZG.png)

Here are the global variables declared in a header file(not important)
[global variable declared in header file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0OHk.png)

Comment: Characters are (small) integers.  So returning a character from an `int`-valued function is fine.

Comment: Please post the code with your question (in text), so all the information can be contained within the StackOverflow post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an integer value as char, you can just make a cast from int to char, like the example:

```
int main() {
    //int cast to char
    int a = 78; //'N' code in ascii table
    printf("%c\n", (char)a); //will print "N"

    //char cast to int
    char c = 't';
    printf("%d\n", (int)c); //will print 116, that is the 't'code in ascii table
}
```

by doing this, your int will be treated as a char. But, you must be careful, because not all integer values have the char representation. For more details, you can search the ascii table. That is a table that codify the characters into integers.
So, because of that, you can treat an integer(not all) as a char and a char as an integer.